# How to best to organize class and interface files?

Tags: c#, interfaces, class, code-organization

OK .. after all the discussion I'm changing my question slightly to better reflect a concrete example that I am dealing with.

---

I have two classes `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo`,  These classes perform similar type of functionality but are unrelated to each other.  However I have a third class `CommonFunc` that contains some public functionality that is implemented in both `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo` and has been factored out as per `DRY`.  The two models are instantiated within the `ModelMain` class (which itself is instantiated at a higher level etc - but I am stopping at this level).

The IoC container that I am using is [Microsoft Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507457(v=pandp.30).aspx).  I don't pretend to be an expert in it, but my understanding of it is that you register a tuple of interface and class with the container and when you want a concrete class you ask the IoC container for whatever object matches a specific interface.  This implies that for every object I want to instantiate from Unity, there has to be a matching interface.  Because each of my classes performs different (and-non-overlapping) functionality this means that there is a 1:1 ratio between interface and class<sup>1</sup>.  However it does not mean that I am slavishly writing an interface for each and every class I write.

Thus code wise I end up with<sup>2</sup>:

```
public interface ICommonFunc 
{ 
}

public interface IModelOne 
{ 
   ICommonFunc Common { get; } 
   .. 
}

public interface IModelTwo
{ 
   ICommonFunc Common { get; } 
   .. 
}

public interface IModelMain 
{ 
  IModelOne One { get; } 
  IModelTwo Two { get; } 
  ..
}

public class CommonFunc : ICommonFunc { .. }

public class ModelOne : IModelOne { .. }

public class ModelTwo : IModelTwo { .. }

public class ModelMain : IModelMain { .. }
```

The question is about how to organize my solution.  Should I keep the class and interface together?  Or should I keep classes and interfaces together?  EG:

**Option 1**  - Organized by class name

```
MySolution
  |
  |-MyProject
  |   |
      |-Models
      |   |
          |-Common
          |   |
          |   |-CommonFunc.cs
          |   |-ICommonFunc.cs
          |
          |-Main
          |   |
          |   |-IModelMain.cs
          |   |-ModelMain.cs
          |
          |-One
          |   |
          |   |-IModelOne.cs
          |   |-ModelOne.cs
          |
          |-Two
              |
              |-IModelTwo.cs
              |-ModelTwo.cs
              |
```

**Option 2** - Organized by functionality (mostly)

```
MySolution
  |
  |-MyProject
  |   |
      |-Models
      |   |
          |-Common
          |   |
          |   |-CommonFunc.cs
          |   |-ICommonFunc.cs
          |
          |-IModelMain.cs
          |-IModelOne.cs
          |-IModelTwo.cs
          |-ModelMain.cs
          |-ModelOne.cs
          |-ModelTwo.cs
          |
```

**Option 3** - Seperating Interface and Implementation

```
MySolution
  |
  |-MyProject
      |
      |-Interfaces
      |   |
      |   |-Models
      |   |   |
      |       |-Common
      |       |   |-ICommonFunc.cs
      |       |
      |       |-IModelMain.cs
      |       |-IModelOne.cs
      |       |-IModelTwo.cs
      |
      |-Classes
          | 
          |-Models
          |   |
              |-Common
              |   |-CommonFunc.cs
              |
              |-ModelMain.cs
              |-ModelOne.cs
              |-ModelTwo.cs
              |
```

**Option 4** - Taking the functionality example further

```
MySolution
  |
  |-MyProject
  |   |
      |-Models
      |   |
          |-Components
          |   |
          |   |-Common
          |   |   |
          |   |   |-CommonFunc.cs
          |   |   |-ICommonFunc.cs
          |   |   
          |   |-IModelOne.cs
          |   |-IModelTwo.cs
          |   |-ModelOne.cs
          |   |-ModelTwo.cs
          |
          |-IModelMain.cs
          |-ModelMain.cs
          |
```

I sort of dislike option 1 because of the class name in the path.  But as I am tending to 1:1 ratio because of my IoC choice/usage (and *that* may be debatable) this has advantages in seeing the relationship between the files.

Option 2 is appealing to me, but now I have muddied the waters between the `ModelMain` and the sub-models.

Option 3 works to separate the interface definition from the implementation, but now I have these artificial breaks in the path names.

Option 4.  I took Option 2 and tweaked it in order to separate the components from the parent model.

Is there good reason for preferring one over the other?  Or any other potential layouts that I have missed?

---

<sup>1.  Frank made a comment that having 1:1 ratio harkens back to C++ days of .h and .cpp files.  I know where he is coming from.  My understanding of Unity seems to put me into this corner, but I am also not sure even how to get out of it if you are also following the adage of `Program to an interface`  But thats a discussion for another day.</sup>

<sup>2.  I have left out the details of each objects constructor.  This is where the IoC container injects objects as required.</sup>

Comment: Ugh. It smells that you have a 1:1 interface/class ratio. Which IoC container are you using? Ninject provides mechanisms that don't require a 1:1 ratio.

Comment: @RubberDuck FWIW I'm using Unity.  I don't claim to be an expert in it, but if my classes are well designed with single responsibilities, how do i *not* end up with almost a 1:1 ratio?

Comment: Do you need IBase or could base be abstract? Why have IDerivedOne when it already implements IBase? You should be depending on IBase, not derived. I don't know about Unity, but other IoC containers allow you to do "context sensitive" injection. Basically when `Client1` needs an `IBase`, it provides a `Derived1`. When `Client2` needs an `IBase`, the IoC provides a `Derived2`.

Comment: @RubberDuck Nominally Base is abstract but I don't see that that changes my question in general.  And Unity is very lightweight/simplistic in its approach.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507499(v=pandp.30).aspx for example

Comment: Well, if base is abstract, then there's no reason to have an `interface` for it. An `interface` is really just an abstract class with all virtual members.

Comment: @RubberDuck then if I want to implement the a public method with the same signature in the two derived classes then you are asking me to define that signature twice.

Comment: No, because you've already defined it in your abstract base class... anyway, Unity is 10 kinds of confusing to me. I tried finding an equivalent method to this, but gave up. The docs are awful. I'm sure some kind of equivalent to Ninject's contextual binding exists though. https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Comment: RubberDuck is correct. Superfluous interfaces are simply annoying.

Comment: @RubberDuck If I do not define the signature in `IMyBase`, then when I ask the IoC for an object that implements `IDerivedOne` I cannot safely cast that to an actual object in order to expose a `public` method that was not defined in the interface.  To do so is to assume the type of object I get back from the IoC.

Comment: @FrankHileman I disagree that `IMyBase` is superfluous if I have a common public method I want to expose in both derived classes.

Comment: Why are you casting? The problem isn't your directory structure or IoC, it's your design. If you're doing dependency injection correctly, your code has no clue an IoC exists. I'm afraid we're not going to get anywhere in the comments without actual code to look at.

Comment: Then make it an abstract method in your base class.

Comment: @RubberDuck The code is irrelevant to my question.  The design I presented was only meant to illustrate my question not be the question.

Comment: It's not irrelevant. You're asking about X, but X is a symptom of Y. If you fix Y, you don't need to X at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62887/discussion-between-peter-m-and-rubberduck).

Comment: `> Or more simply, can you do testing by adding conditionally-compiled code into the actual classes? C# provides modern ways of conditional compilation`. What fresh hell is this?

Answer (score 8):

Since an interface is abstractly similar to a base class, use the same logic you would use for a base class. Classes implementing an interface are closely related to the interface.

I doubt you would prefer a directory called "Base Classes"; most developers would not want that, nor a directory called "Interfaces". In c#, directories are also namespaces by default, making it doubly confusing.

The best approach is to think about how you would break up the classes/interfaces if you had to put some into a separate library, and organize the namespaces/directories in a similar manner. The .net framework design guidelines has [namespace suggestions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces) that may be helpful.

Comment: I am sort of familiar with the link you provided, but I am not sure how it relates to file organization.  While VS defaults to path names for the initial namespace I know that this is an arbitrary choice.  Also I have update my code 'sample' and layout possibilities.

Comment: @PeterM I am not sure which IDE you are using, but Visual Studio does use the directory names to automatically generate the namespace declarations when adding a class, for instance. This means that while you can have differences between directory names and namespace names, it is more painful to work that way. So most people don't do that.

Comment: I am using VS.  And yes I know pain.  It brings back memories of Visual Source Safe file layout.

Comment: @PeterM With regard to 1:1 interface to class ratio. Some tools require this. I view this as a defect of the tool -- .net has enough reflection capabilities to not need such restrictions in any such tool.

Answer (score 3):

As always with any design question, the first thing to do is determine who are your users. How are they going to use your organization?

Are they coders who will be using your classes? Then separating the interfaces from the code may be best.

Are they maintainers of your code? Then keep the interfaces and classes together may be best.

Sit down and create some use-cases. Then the best organization may appear before you.

Comment: What if it's both?

Answer (score 1):

I do take the second approach, with some more folders/namespaces in complex projects of course. It means that I de-couple the interfaces from the concrete implementations.

In a different project, you may have to know the interface definition, but it is not at all necessary to know any concrete class implementing it - especially when you use an IoC container. So those other projects only need to reference the interface projects, not the implementation projects. This can keep references low, and can prevent circular reference issues.

Comment: I have revised my code example and added some more options

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to store interfaces in the separate library. 
Firstly, this kind of design increases dependence. That's why the implementation of these interfaces can be made by another programming language.